# Cypress 'Refused to frame' issue

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, cypress

I'm using Cypress to run end-to-end tests on an our application. All test were good but we have a feature and with this feature user integrate their bank account via then they're landing our page and we're showing some extra stuff and it continues. Until bank integration, everything is fine. When it comes to integration I'm sending user via link to external provider, then I've got an error.

*cypress -v `5.6.0`*

`Refused to frame 'https://login.truelayer.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://somelink.github.io".`

on config file `"chromeWebSecurity": false`

**What I tried?**

On csp.js file, I updated `'frame-ancestors': ['https://somelink.github.io, 'https://*.amazon.com',]`   and it didn't work.
Is there any way that I can tackle this?